# SQLite3: update not working correctly?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to update 4 columns on an SQLite database from my C program using the code below:

```
const char* update = {
    "UPDATE mytable SET "
    "mycolumn1"
    "=?,"
    "mycolumn2"
    "=?,"
    "mycolumn3"
    "=?,"
    "mycolumn4"
    "=? WHERE(id=1);"
};
extern sqlite3 *sqdb;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int val[2]={1, 2};
sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqdb, update, -1, &stmt, 0);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, val[0], 1);
sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 2, L"example1", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 3, L"example2", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, val[1], 4);
sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

that does the update successfully, however only the 2 text columns(column 2 & 3) gets updated and the other 2 int columns are not updated and they contains an empty value, I tested that using the SQLite command shell after exporting the database to be used by the shell.

so what's wrong? and how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the arguments in wrong order:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, val[0], 1);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, val[1], 4);
```

the second argument is the index, the third argument is the value. Since both are of type `int` here, there's no compile-time error.

Change to:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, val[0]);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, val[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) says:

> The second argument is the index of the SQL parameter to be set.

You exchanged the second and third `sqlite3_bind_int` arguments.